# Production environnement, SSL and socket.io error

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io

**Context**

We have recently put in production one of our NodeJS server.

We user Express 4.x and Socket.IO 1.x, on the same port like Socket.IO documentation explains that.

- It's listening on a port 10 000 and using Express + Socket.IO
- On the same machine, we have an angular frontend accessible from a NginX server.
- The NginX server has a reverse proxy redirection from /api to the NodeJS server
- So, when the front(Angular) send a request to /api, it well get the data resultset it needs
- We add a redirection on /socket.io, the polling request from Socket.IO library from port 80 to our NodeJS server on port 10000
- The redirections works great in the sense that I have many requests on the server.

**Problem**

Actually, we can access /api in production. But it seems that I have a problem with the calls on /socket.io. In fact, each polling request (so many in our case) sends me a stack like the following one.

*NB : we dont have this problem on dev environnement (Windows Server) but we have it on a Debian in production.*

*NB2 : we use a SSL certificate on NGINX (the reverse proxy that handles the requests)*

**Error**.

```
12)
  at next (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
  at query (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:28:5)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
  at trim_prefix (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
  at /isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
  at Function.proto.process_params (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
  at next (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
  at Function.proto.handle (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:3)
  at EventEmitter.app.handle (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:170:10)
  at Server.app (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:28:9)
  at Server.<anonymous> (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:369:22)
  at Server.<anonymous> (/isp/www/effi-report.com/www/api/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:258:16)
  at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
  at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
  at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
```

Comment: It seems to be missing the actual error message.

Comment: The is only what I can read from my nodejs  console